# Python 3 - simple thing about formatting my output

Tags: python-3.x

The following code returns the tokens at different levels:

```
import re

def matches(line, opendelim='(', closedelim=')'):
stack = []

for m in re.finditer(r'[{}{}]'.format(opendelim, closedelim), line):
    pos = m.start()

    if line[pos-1] == '\\':
        continue

    c = line[pos]

    if c == opendelim:
        stack.append(pos+1)

    elif c == closedelim:
        if len(stack) > 0:
            prevpos = stack.pop()
            yield (line[prevpos:pos], len(stack))
        else:
            print("encountered extraneous closing quote at pos {}: '{}'".format(pos, line[pos:] ))
            pass

if len(stack) > 0:
    for pos in stack:
        print("expecting closing quote to match open quote starting at: '{}'"
              .format(line[pos-1:]))

line = 'f_0(a,f_1(b,f_2(f_3(f_4(a)),f_3(h)),f_2(f_3(a))),f_1(f_2(f_3(a))))'
for part, level in matches(line):
    if level == 2:
        print(part)
```

gives me the following output:

```
f_3(f_4(a)),f_3(h)
f_3(a)
f_3(a)
```

is there a way i can format my output in the below form? :

```
['f_3(f_4(a))', 'f_3(h)', 'f_3(a)', 'f_3(a)']
```

I am new to python. Can i please get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and print all the result at once:

```
print [part for part, level in matches(line) if level == 2]
```

Also you can join your result :

```
print ','.join([part for part, level in matches(line) if level == 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This almost gives me what i need : ['f_3(f_4(a)),f_3(h)', 'f_3(a)', 'f_3(a)']

Comment: @hmm welcome! now you can tell this to community by accepting the answer ;)!

Comment: can you also tell me if there is a way to return my output in the following form : f_3(f_4(a)),f_3(h),f_3(a),f_3(a) and assign it to a variable so that i can give it as an input to another function?

Comment: @hmm you can use `join` function! check the edit out!